# Passing variable in PHP script: Getting message about converting PDO object to int

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I have an MSSQL table with a data column (ApproverType) of type smallint. It only contains a number from 1-9.

I have a query written to grab the value of this column on submit when it matches a selected e-mail address:

```
$approv = $con->prepare("SELECT ApproverType FROM ApproverList WHERE ApproverEmail =     
:email");
$data = array('email'=>$_POST['approvEmail']);
$approv->execute($data);
$row = $approv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
$approvRole = $row['ApproverType'];
```

This works fine, and the variable gets passed to my functions, but at the end of the post, I get the following notice:

```
Notice: Object of class PDO could not be converted to int in MyScript on line xxx
```

It isn't causing anything to stop working, but it's annoying and I'd like to eliminate it. I thought changing my query to fetchAll would work, but that actually doesn't return anything. Using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC gets me my value, but doesn't make the message go away.

Here is an example of a line where the notice is occurring. I use this variable in a switch() statement.

```
switch($approvRole)
{
    case 5: //5 is $approvRole
    $url = someurl;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Which of those lines does `line xxx` refer to? If none, could you show us that line.

Comment: Too bad. PHP normally tells you the exact line number where the error is detected, which makes bug fixing very simple, but you're getting `xxx` instead :(

Comment: Here's an example of a line where the notice is occurring:
`switch($approvRole)
  {
  case 5: //GCA
  $url = someurl;
  break;
         }`

Comment: `var_dump($approvRole);`

Comment: var_dump() returns it as a string.

Comment: Are you 100% that's row number xxx? Neither `$approvRole` is a PDO object, nor `swith()` will cast to int...

Comment: Yes, that is the first line where I encounter the notice.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be

```
    $data = array(':email'=>$_POST['approvEmail']);

-------------------^
```

Comment: Nah, you don't need to include the : in your data array.

Answer (score 0):

On this line :

```
 $row = $approv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

It returned a PDO object but it should be an array right? There may have been an error before that code. On on how you have prepared your `$data` , that is why it was not fetching properly. You can also try:

```
 $row = $approv->fetch();
```

, I also think that it should be :